# Configmap containing folders and all sub-folders \ files - mounted as a volume

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, mounted-volumes

What I would like to have is a github repo, containing multiple folders and files to be available as a configmap, for the services to mount as volumes and use them, as it where local files.

We can add files (or folders) to this repo - and the configmap when updated - should make sure these files are also available for the services.

I am able to create a configmap

```
kubectl create configmap my-config --from-file=/my-repo/
```

But the configmap has only the files under the folder, not the sub-folders and files in them.

How can I mount the entire folder such that they are available for the services to use?

Comment: You don't: a ConfigMap doesn't contain directory structure, only a list of string-key/string-value pairs.  What exactly is going into this ConfigMap?  Should some of it go into your image instead?

Comment: @davi the target is to have all the folders and files (in a repo) available for the services as a volume mounted. I am able to do that for all files in a single folder, by mounting the configmap as a volume

Comment: IME a ConfigMap is good for "a couple" of files, but what you're describing sounds like you want to add a Dockerfile to the repository, build it into an image, and deploy that.  The ConfigMap makes sense for specific individual config files but not necessarily an entire repository.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a ConfigMap in Kubernetes using kubectl create configmap, it does not automatically include sub-folders and files in your directory. You'll need to explicitly include all the files and directories you want in your ConfigMap. However, you can automate this process with a script or use Kubernetes resources like ConfigMap and Volume to achieve what you want. Here's a step-by-step guide:

**Create a ConfigMap that includes all your files and directories** :

You can use kubectl create configmap or a YAML file to define your ConfigMap. Here's an example YAML file that includes files and directories from a local directory:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-config
data:
  file1.txt: |-
    <contents of file1.txt>
  file2.txt: |-
    <contents of file2.txt>
  subdir/file3.txt: |-
    <contents of file3.txt>
```

In the above example, the ConfigMap includes three files, including one in a subdirectory.

**Apply the ConfigMap**:

Use kubectl apply to create or update the ConfigMap:

```bash
$ kubectl apply -f my-configmap.yaml
```

Mount the ConfigMap as a volume in your pod:

You can now mount this ConfigMap as a volume in your pods. Here's an example Pod YAML that mounts the ConfigMap as a volume:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: your-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /config
  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
      name: my-config
```

In this Pod definition, the ConfigMap is mounted as a volume at the path /config. This means you can access the files and directories from the ConfigMap as if they were local files within your container.

With this setup, any changes to your ConfigMap will be reflected in your pods. If you add or modify files in the ConfigMap, the pods using it will automatically see those changes without needing to recreate the pods.

Comment: This does not take care of new files and folders added to the directory - as we need to also update the configmap then. Also the configmap has a size limitation of 1-1.5MB. How are you going to deal with it?